# Check function execution completion

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic system where developers can "plugin" their functions into the different functionalities of the system. I'd like to trigger events once their functions are fully executed, but the problem is : I don't know anything about their functions (if they use async, promises ... )

Here is an example of what a plugin looks like :

```js
var plugins = {

  // async
  onInit: async function () {
    return await x;
  },
  
  // promise
  onMount: function (selector) {
    fetch('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask').then(res => $selector.append('something'));
  },
  
  // normal function
  onUnmount: function () {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Here is how I'm handling the code :

```js
/// Inside my class implementation.

static factory (configurations) {
        var self = this;

        return class CustomStep extends Question {

            constructor (param1, param2) {
                // Call Question's constructor.
                super (param1, param2)

                // Assign input configs as public properties & functions. 
                for (let key in configurations) {
                    let value = configurations[key];
                    if (typeof value === 'function') {
                        this[key] = async function () {
                        
                        ////// => Here is where I execute the plugin's function
                        ////// Is it possible to know when it is completed ?
                            await value.bind(this)(arguments);

                            let event = "";
                            let data  = {};

                            switch (key) {
                                case 'init':
                                    event = `${this.id}:${this.v}:${this.#EVENTS.INIT}`;
                                    break;
                                case 'mount':
                                    event = `${this.id}:${this.v}:${this.#EVENTS.MOUNT}`;
                                    break;
                                case 'unmount':
                                    event = `${this.id}:${this.v}:${this.#EVENTS.UNMOUNT}`;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }

                            this.#trigger(event, data);
                        }
                    } else {
                        this[key] = value;    
                    }
                }
                
                // Call the plugin's init function.
                this.init();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If callback-based functions don't have to be handled, then both `Promise.resolve(func()).then(...)` or `await func()` is fine, where `func` is the function you want to call. Note that, however, in case of using raw promises (like `onMount`), `func` has to return its promise in order for that to work

Comment: The problem is that your example plugin does not actually return a promise from its `onMount` method. If it did, your code would simply work.

Comment: Is this Node.js or browser code?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Eventually browser code, will be compiled using gulp/browserify/babel stack.

Comment: @Bergi certainly ! This why I'm asking here. Javascript ought to know (for internal reasons at least) when a function is executed, non ?

Comment: There could be a browser specific solution checking the event loop https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#what-is-the-event-loop

Comment: @user2517028 JavaScript (the runtime) knows, but without a `return`, the plugin won't let the caller know that it started some asynchronous processing - for all purposes of the caller, the function is finished and has returned `undefined`. Not sure what else you would be expecting.